# Make Twitter Bootstrap's typead search within multiple fields

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

By default, the [typeahead plugin](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) makes use of a single data source in order to fetch the results. What I would like is for it to search within multiple fields, so if say, I have:

```
var items = [
    {'title': 'Acceptable', 'description': 'Good, but not great'}
]
```

It will search on both the `title` and `description` fields, ideally via AJAX.

Is this possible with this plugin?

Comment: You can easily override the `matcher` callback by passing a customised one in the options. AJAX functionality can be added by creating a `source` callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeahead does not support using JSON objects without two tweaks. There are few pull-requests in Github for this, and I have [submitted one myself](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/7298), but, currently, you must manually override `select` and `render`.  Additionally, you must also override `highlighter`, `matcher`, `sorter`, and `updater`, but those can done via the options passed into the typeahead.

```
var typeahead = control.typeahead({ /* ... */ }).data('typeahead');

// manually override select and render
//  (change attr('data-value' ...) to data('value' ...))
//  otherwise both functions are exact copies
typeahead.select = function() {
    var val = this.$menu.find('.active').data('value')
    this.$element.val(this.updater(val)).change()
    return this.hide()
};
typeahead.render = function(items) {
    var that = this

    items = $(items).map(function (i, item) {
        i = $(that.options.item).data('value', item)
        i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item))
        return i[0]
    });

    items.first().addClass('active')
    this.$menu.html(items)
    return this
};
```

If you need help with the other ones, then let me know, but the gist of it is:

```
control.typehead({
    matcher: function (item) {
        var lcQuery = this.query.toLowerCase();
        return ~item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(lcQuery)
            || ~item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(lcQuery);
    }
};
```

I also have a [JFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mtxkn/15/) related to the pull request that I made, but the sorting functions do not exist in 2.3.1, or even 3.x without the pull request being accepted, so you will have to override `sorter` in its entirety to effectively repeat what I did with `matcher` above (checking both while sorting).

As for the AJAX call, you can override the `source` method in the passed in options to get AJAX functionality. By not returning to the `source` call, it assumes that the second parameter, `process,` will be invoked with results.

```
control.typehead({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function(query, process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url + encodeURIComponent(query),
            type: 'GET',
            success: process,
            error: function() { /* ... */ }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Typeahead added support for multiple field searching in v10.3
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/811

Usage:
`datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('title', 'description'),`